# Load a class which implements another one - Java

Tags: java, class, dynamic, reflection

I'm trying to load some classes dynamically by getting their bytes and using reflection to use the defineClass method. Here is my code (this is a loop)

```
Method m = java.lang.ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("defineClass", String.class, byte[].class, int.class, int.class);
            m.setAccessible(true);
            m.invoke(Main.class.getClassLoader(), className, classBytes, 0, classBytes.length);
```

But when a class implements another one, it throws a NoClassDefFoundError (the implemented class isn't load yet). I don't know how to do, I tried to load few times to resolve this but it doesn't work. I also searched to add all classes to the classpath before loading them but I don't know how to do this with an array of byte.

Comment: Are you sure the class name you're passing matches the class defined by the bytes in your array?  Do note that it is the *binary* name that is expected, which differs from the form used in Java source code.  Or you should be able to sidestep that whole issue by passing `null` as the class name, provided you are confident that your bytes define the class you want.

Comment: Yes it matches, and even if I pass `null` as parameter, it doesn't find the implemented class. It's strange because without implementing a class it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic class loader is what Java does. There shouldn't be a need to bypass language access restrictions. Subclass `SecureClassLoader` in the usual way.

Comment: You mean that I should use `SecureClassLoader` without reflection instead of `ClassLoader` with reflection ?

Comment: @outrage There will be some reflection to use the class. But you don't need to be messing with `setAccessible`.

Comment: Oh ok I see but the difference is just that there are permissions right ? I added the CodeSource of the class which loads the byte array and it still throwing me the error about the implemented class which can't be found (not loaded yet). `Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()`

Comment: @outrage No. Use `loadClass` get hold of the `Class` externally. Implement `findClass` to define the class. There's some examples code in the API docs for `java.lang.ClassLoader`.